# Grails: URL mapping changing the controller name

Tags: grails

This must be a simple config in URLMappings.groovy, but I keep getting a 404.

Basically, I want to change the name of a controller. For example, we have controller name Content_pdfs_data_etcController.groovy, awful as a URL, I tried

```
static mappings = {
    "/mdata/$action?"(controller: "content_pdfs_data_etc", action: 'index')

    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/"(view:"/index")
    "/"(controller:"home")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

All actions in the controller should get redirected as well (example):

/mdata/show    ->   content_pdfs_data_etc/show

/mdata/update  ->   content_pdsf_data_etc/update

Thanks.

Comment: BTW what's the reason behind keep the controller name as Content_pdfs_data_etcController

Comment: It was another developer that named the controller, client came back and asked to changed the URL. I know I could have just renamed the controller/view directory.

Comment: Yeah, it would be better to rename the controller, if you have control on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Andrew. I actually figured out that swapping the order of the mapping with the default fixed the issue. I ended up with:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
    // apply constraints here
    }
}
"/mdata/$action?/$id?" (controller: "content_pdfs_data_etc")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the hard-coded action, which should allow the $action variable to do its mapping magic:

```
"/mdata/$action?"(controller: "content_pdfs_data_etc")
```